# Linq with Different Where clauses and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to have a generic method that get's different results from a query, based on a 'Search Object'I pass in.

Basically, based on certain conditions, I want to add Where clause conditions.

But I want to execute the query once. So, no `toList()` everywhere. I want to make the database do all the work.

My method is now like this:

```
 public async Task<List<TransactionBasicDto>> GetListAsync(TransactionListFilterRequest request)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                var userAccount = context.UserAccounts.First(x => x.ExternalId == _jwt.HomeAccountId);

                var data = context.TransactionLine
                    .Include(x => x.Transaction)
                    .Include(x => x.Transaction.CreditAccount)
                    .Include(x => x.Transaction.DebitAccount)
                    .Where(x => x.Transaction.CreditAccount.UserAccount == userAccount && x.Transaction.Deleted == null);

                if (request.FromDate.HasValue)
                    data = data.Where(x => x.Transaction.Date >= request.FromDate);

                if (request.ToDate.HasValue)
                    data = data.Where(x => x.Transaction.Date <= request.ToDate);

                if (request.AccountId.HasValue)
                    data = data.Where(x => x.Transaction.CreditAccount.ExternalId == request.AccountId || x.Transaction.DebitAccount.ExternalId == request.AccountId);

                if (request.LimitResultCount.HasValue)
                    data = data.Take(request.LimitResultCount.Value);

                if (request.HistoricDaysFromNow.HasValue)
                    data = data.Where(x => x.Transaction.Date >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(request.HistoricDaysFromNow.Value * -1));
                try
                {
                    var g = data
                    .GroupBy(x => new
                    {
                        Id = x.Transaction.ExternalId,
                        CreateOrder = x.Transaction.Id,
                        Date = x.Transaction.Date,
                        DebitAccountId = x.Transaction.DebitAccount.ExternalId,
                        DebitAccountName = x.Transaction.DebitAccount.Name,
                        DebitAccountTypeId = x.Transaction.DebitAccount.AccountTypeId,
                        CreditAccountId = x.Transaction.CreditAccount.ExternalId,
                        CreditAccountName = x.Transaction.CreditAccount.Name,
                        CreditAccountTypeId = x.Transaction.CreditAccount.AccountTypeId,
                        Description = x.Transaction.Description,
                    })
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Id = x.Key.Id,
                        CreateOrder = x.Key.CreateOrder,
                        Date = x.Key.Date,
                        TransactionTypeId = WorkOutType(x.Key.DebitAccountTypeId, x.Key.CreditAccountTypeId),
                        DebitAccountId = x.Key.DebitAccountId,
                        DebitAccountName = x.Key.DebitAccountName,
                        CreditAccountId = x.Key.CreditAccountId,
                        CreditAccountName = x.Key.CreditAccountName,
                        Description = x.Key.Description,
                        Amount = x.Sum(y => y.Amount)
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                    .ThenByDescending(x => x.CreateOrder)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(x => new TransactionBasicDto
                    {
                        Amount = x.Amount,
                        Date = x.Date,
                        CreditAccountId = x.CreditAccountId,
                        CreditAccountName = x.CreditAccountName,
                        DebitAccountId = x.DebitAccountId,
                        DebitAccountName = x.DebitAccountName,
                        Description = x.Description,
                        Id = x.Id,
                        TransactionTypeId = x.TransactionTypeId
                    })
                    .ToList();

                    return g;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var b = e;
                    throw;
                }


            }
```

Problem is that my GroupBy fails now. When I remove all the `data = data...` and have the GroupBy right after the first .Where, it works.

But it seems when I separate it and add the conditional wheres, it breaks with the error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

This happens within the try/catch.

It's as if I am not allowd to split the statement.

Before, I had:

```
.Where(x => x.Transaction.CreditAccount.UserAccount == userAccount && x.Transaction.Deleted == null)
.GroupBy(x => new
                    {
                        Id = x.Transaction.ExternalId,
                        CreateOrder = x.Transaction.Id,
```

And that worked. But splitting the statement to add those where Where clauses causes this error. Am I doing it wrong?

> at System.SharedTypeExtensions.GetSequenceType(Type type)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitMainFromClause(MainFromClause
>   fromClause, QueryModel queryModel)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Clauses.MainFromClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor
>   visitor, QueryModel queryModel)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ProjectionExpressionVisitor.VisitSubQuery(SubQueryExpression
>   expression)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitAndConvert[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1
>   nodes, String callerName)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.RelinqExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression
>   expression)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression
>   newExpression)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause
>   selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause
>   selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Clauses.SelectClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor,
>   QueryModel queryModel)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel
>   queryModel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel
>   queryModel)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](Expression
>   query, IQueryModelGenerator queryModelGenerator, IDatabase database,
>   IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object
>   cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object
>   cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   query)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1
>   enumerable)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   DataAccess.Concrete.TransactionData.GetListAsync(TransactionListFilterRequest
>   request) in C:\Storage\Software
>   Repositories\Personal\AccuFinanceV2Backend\ Backend\04.
>   DataAccess\Concrete\TransactionData.cs:line 374

Comment: How about when you remove only .Take and .Include methods, and leave .Where methods as they are. Do you still have the exception?

Comment: WIll try the suggestion, @pegasuspect

Comment: Are you using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Remotion.Linq/ ?

Comment: Hang on. Removing the 'Take' has resulted in no exception. No data either, but that might just be my conditions. Checking. @mjwills - I'm not aware of that package.

Comment: Turn on [client evaluation warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#optional-behavior-throw-an-exception-for-client-evaluation) - the query contains some constructs which may affect that - `UserAccount == userAccount` (try using `Id` property for comparison), `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays` (try moving this calculation in a variable outside the query), `WorkOutType(…)` call (this definitely cannot be translated, try implementing what it does "inplace", so the translator can "see" it) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Trying an approach where the `Where` predicate is built up completely before the first Where is called.

After some research I came across multiple incarnation of the [`PredicateBuilder`](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/)

Reference [A universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/)

Reference [Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

and modified it to suit my needs.

```
public static class PredicateBuilder {
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return x => true; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return x => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) { return predicate; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right) {
        return left.Compose(right, Expression.OrElse);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right) {
        return left.Compose(right, Expression.AndAlso);
    }

    static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> left, Expression<T> right, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge) {
        var p1 = left.Parameters.First();//Only handling with one parameter
        // replace parameters in the second lambda expression with the parameters in the first
        var rightBody = ParameterRebinder.Replaceparameter(p1, right.Body);
        // create a merged lambda expression with parameters from the first expression
        return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(left.Body, rightBody), left.Parameters);
    }

    private class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor {
        private ParameterExpression source;

        public ParameterRebinder(ParameterExpression source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        internal static Expression Replaceparameter(ParameterExpression source, Expression root) {
            return new ParameterRebinder(source).Visit(root);// (Expression<TOutput>)VisitLambda(root);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
            // Replace non matching parameters, visit other params as usual.
            return node.Name != source.Name ? source : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

With that the predicate is constructed first based on the desired conditions...

```
//...

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<TransactionLine>(x => x.Transaction.CreditAccount.UserAccount == userAccount && x.Transaction.Deleted == null);

if (request.FromDate.HasValue)
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Transaction.Date >= request.FromDate);

if (request.ToDate.HasValue)
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Transaction.Date <= request.ToDate);

if (request.AccountId.HasValue)
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Transaction.CreditAccount.ExternalId == request.AccountId || x.Transaction.DebitAccount.ExternalId == request.AccountId);

if (request.HistoricDaysFromNow.HasValue)
    predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Transaction.Date >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(request.HistoricDaysFromNow.Value * -1));

//...
```

And then applied to the target collection in one call

```
//...

var data = context.TransactionLine
    .Include(x => x.Transaction)
    .Include(x => x.Transaction.CreditAccount)
    .Include(x => x.Transaction.DebitAccount)
    .Where(predicate);

if (request.LimitResultCount.HasValue)
    data = data.Take(request.LimitResultCount.Value);

try{
    var g = data
        .GroupBy(x => ...


//...
```

Comment: What is the difference? Chained `Where` are known to be the exact equivalent of `&&` predicates. `PredicateBuilder` is useful for `||` (or mixed) type predicates which have no equivalent LINQ construct. IMHO this won't solve the issue (whatever it is - from stack trace looks like it's related to some `Select`).

Comment: @IvanStoev I thought it would help simplify the conditional filter/predicate.